# Auto input answer for a terminal command within python script

Tags: python

I made a python script in which it runs a specified terminal command.

```
def main(my_list):
    for item in my_list:
        os.system("myCmd -s {0}".format(item))

    item_list = ['itemA', 'itemB', 'itemC']
    main(item_list)
```

As the terminal command I am trying to use does not accepts a list in the `-s` argument, which is the reason that I make it into a python script.
While running the script, it works but I notice that it will prompts me with the following question:
`Are you sure you want to continue (y/n)?`

This means I will need to punch in the `y` on my keyboard, 3 times in the above example.
But in the event if my list is huge, and should I not be on my desk, is there any way that I can script to make it accept 'y' as my answer, without me to press anything on the keyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to use a [pipe](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pipes.html), that way you can actually write to that pipe an answer, don't forget to close the pipe once you're done with it.

```
p = os.popen("myCmd -s {0}".format(item), "w")
p.write("y\n")
```

[`popen`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.popen) documentation

Comment: Glad I could help @dissidia

Answer (score 1):

Use the **pexpect module**.  It's basically **expect** used in shell scripts, for Python.

Comment: I did not get a chance to test this as it appears I need to install it. But I'm sure it works as well!