# Passing in responses to input() prompts in python through system arguments

Tags: python-3.x, command-prompt, argv

I'm using a python library that has a configuration step which involves calling a function and providing the API key in the prompt response. It uses `input()`. This function creates the file necessary with all the configurations.

This is fine for humans to use the API, but I'm adding CI to my code and wish to unit tests calls to this API. As such, I need to complete the same step.

I simply want to do something like `python -c '<PYTHON CODE>'`.

Aside from altering the code to allow for an optional input of the API key (to skip the prompt), I wonder if there is an easier way to do this with `sys.argv`.

I did some googling and could not find a working example involving `input()` and argument inputs.

Thoughts appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at the `argparse` library.

Comment: Familiar with `argparse`, but I don't see how I could pass this into a call of `api_key = input("what's your API key? : ")`

Comment: Either you input using `input()`, or using an argument parser, such as `sys.argv` or, better, `argparse`, as mentioned by @enzo. Or even both, and pick one to use at runtime. It is unclear to me what exactly you want or expect as an answer

Comment: @MatBBastos, I'm trying to keep my question general while still explaining context. In short, is there a way to pass arguments to functions that use `input()` without modifying the original code? I just don't want it to prompt for human input.

Comment: Would you be executing the original code from a file, without 'seeing' it?
If you are executing it as a script, you can make an 'outer script' that executes it and provides input when necessary. That doesn't even have to be in Python, though it could.

Comment: If what I commented is in line with what you want, both [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51624128/12818877) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43104495/12818877) answers might be helpful

Comment: My hope is a simple one-liner in a GitLab CI YAML file to import the library and pass in the API key and build the configuration file.

Comment: Can't you set another element in the YAML file to point to a `.env` file or something like that? This way, you can use `python-dotenv` to get the values, for example. It's a clean solution, which avoids hardcoding anything into the original code (though requires making minor changes to it)